# Changing naming strategy of @Table and @Column with EclipseLink to lower-case

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

When defining a JPA Entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class CaseExample implements Serializable {
    @Id
    Long id;
    @Basic
    String fooBar;
}
```

the automatically created SQL table name is "CASEEXAMPLE" and the column name "FOOBAR".
How can I change that from upper-case to lower-case-with-underscore e.g. "case_example" and "foo_bar" **without** having to add a name="foo_bar" to every single @Table and @Column?

Is the naming strategy defined by JPA or implemenation dependend? I use JPA 2.0 with EclipseLink 2.5.0.

Comment: what is the target database? and the OS?

Comment: It's MySQL 5.6 on Debian GNU/Linux "sid".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA standardizes the names.  I would leave them using the standard, or use @Column to change specific ones.

With EclipseLink you could modify you column names using your own code in a DescriptorCustomizer or SessionCustomizer.  You would just iterate over your descriptor's mapping and reset the fieldNames based on your naming convention.

Comment: Thanks, using SessionCustomizer as search term I now found the following answer which provides an example:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441931/eclipselink-custom-table-and-column-naming-strategy

Comment: Could you link to the part of the standard that talks about table/column naming conventions?