# EclipseLink: default column names are changed to uppercase

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    private String foo;
    //+getters and setters
}
```

So, ecpliselink will generate the following query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.FOO FROM ...
```

I've noticed that all default column names (which I didn't set via @Column) are changed to uppercase. I tried to set `eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names` to  `false` but it didn't help. How can I make eclipselink get the column names from the class fields without modification?

Comment: This questions is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18700346/5078385. There is also another useful information in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15911225/5078385. Isn't that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA standardizes the names to uppercase. With the property `eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names` your're only able to force JDBC return column names in upper case in order to match with default naming in upper case.

If you don't want to use the Annotation `@Column` to overwrite the default naming of your columns, you could use a SessionCustomizer or a DescriptorCustomizer. Both ways will work with eclipselink and are very well described on this site [Link with example  of SessionCustomizer & :DescriptorCustomizer](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Customizers#DescriptorCustomizer_example)